# TS return type based on arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm working on a TypeScript project and I'm encountering a type error that I can't seem to resolve. Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
type OptionMode = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';

const Foo = <Mode extends OptionMode>(
  mode: Mode
): Mode extends 'A' ? string : number => {
  // Your implementation here

  // Example implementation:
  if (mode === 'A') {
    return 'This is a string';// ERROR: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Mode extends "A" ? string : number'.(2322)
  } else {
    return 1 // ERROR:Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Mode extends "A" ? string : number'.(2322)

  }
};


const stringResult = Foo( 'A');
const numberResult= Foo( 'B');
```

In this code, I'm trying to create a function Foo that returns either a string or a number based on the input mode. However, I'm getting the following errors:

- `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Mode extends "A" ? string : number'.(2322)`
- `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Mode extends "A" ? string : number'.(2322)`

I'm having trouble understanding why these errors are occurring and how to fix them. Can someone help me understand what's going wrong and how to make this code work as intended?

Thank you!

Comment: My writeup uses the conditional type as a parameter but it's the same idea. https://kelsny.github.io/typescript/conditional-type-abuse

Comment: Hm, I'll need to update it sometime soon, but skip the discriminated unions part. You should use overloads at the very least (described in greater detail in the linked article), or when I get to update it, an external overload/signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is unable to narrow generic types based on narrowing the type of a variable set to that generic type. The reason why this is not possible to do rigorously becomes clearer when working with generic functions that have multiple arguments that refer to its generic type. For example:

```js
type OptionMode = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';

declare const Foo: <Mode extends OptionMode>(
  first: Mode,
  second: Mode
) => Mode extends 'A' ? string : number;

const stringResult = Foo('A', 'A'); // <- `Mode` is inferred as 'A'
const numberResult = Foo('A', 'B'); // <- `Mode` is inferred as 'A' | 'B'
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AskgJtAvFA5AIL5QA+BAQiefgML4DcAUE9gMYA2AhgE7RuoAzsCgAxJEgBcUADwZsUCAA9gEFJkGx4ydFggA+ABRMoUAGYIew6fIgAaE1EEQB6m3qYBKKDn1RbiipqGgTEUAD8TsA8CCgA5lDSKACuALYARhA8zEyuwlEx8QBKEILJHCJ44kiGRPh2ofieDFAA9K2yALRQAAa2PVAImrFmWXyYUFyadblCIikZWSVlFT5iErXEDfhUzW0dMt19egNDgyijPOOT02E0VExAA)

As this example hopefully makes clear, because your generic type could be a union containing multiple members of `OptionMode`, there is no way for TypeScript to narrow it based on the runtime type of one of its arguments.

There is a change that may come in TypeScript 5.3 that will [allow some narrowing of generic types](https://www.totaltypescript.com/typescript-5-3#narrowing-in-generic-functions) by narrowing arguments, but that narrowing will come in the form of setting a **lower limit** to the generic type. For example, if your `mode` argument has the value `'A'`, then `Mode` definitely **contains** the type `'A'`, but it could still be a union containing that type.

When function arguments need to be narrowed together, this can be resolved by defining them using spread syntax with a tuple type, where that tuple is a discriminated union. This allows TypeScript to narrow the types of multiple arguments when just one of them is narrowed. But in cases like this, where it's the function's return type that needs to change, that's not possible.

That's why overloads work, as in the answer you posted. But it's worth mentioning that overloads can be difficult to maintain. TypeScript won't check that your implementation matches all your overloads, and if you have a lot of overloads they will all need to be written out manually.

Anther approach you could use involves defining a type that specified a return type based on each `OptionMode`, and then indexing into that type from your generic function instead of using a conditional type. This still isn't a perfect solution - it has the same potential problem with union types for example, and until the update I mentioned may be coming in TypeScript 5.3 it requires type assertions - but in some cases it may be easier to maintain than an overload-based solution.

```js
type OptionMode = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';

type ModeData = {
  A: string;
  B: number;
  C: number;
};

const Foo = <Mode extends OptionMode>(
  mode: Mode
): ModeData[Mode] {
  if (mode === 'A') {
    return 'This is a string' as ModeData[Mode];
  } else {
    return 1 as ModeData[Mode];
  }
}

const stringResult = Foo('A'); // <- string
const numberResult = Foo('A'); // <- number
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AskgJtAvFA5AIL5QA+BAQiefgML4DcAUE6JFBtgCICGwPUPAG8mUKIQBcUAM7AATghQBzZmIpSUAVwC2AIwhzVUWhp37DTAL7MmAY1SyoAMSRJBUADydoEAB7AIFExpWHhkdCwIAD4AClEobUipbyYASmTI3n4AbW8AXSgRMQQAMygYxOxBHDwifFTC+LE5CGBNORQCABUACwQQ-qgBWQVlEh4Q7yyeXMi8o0soCAAbaWgisSgWto6oAEYhycy+GfyFqxZ7FEcRxSUAJQhpTWXgdxckGLrUhigAej+ngAtDJ5Hc7A43lo9AZHs9Xu9XF9iD9-oCPCDoeYmEA)

As you can see, I've had to use `as ModeData[Mode]` when returning values in this example. But after the "lower bound" change I mentioned is shipped, those type assertions should be able to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks kelsny

```
type OptionMode = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';

function Foo(mode: 'A'): string;
function Foo(mode: 'B' | 'C'): number;
function Foo(mode: OptionMode): string | number {
  // Your implementation here

  // Example implementation:
  if (mode === 'A') {
    return 'This is a string';
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}

const stringResult = Foo('A'); // stringResult is of type 'string'
const numberResult = Foo('B'); // numberResult is of type 'number
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I prepared a [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WGXE9w) anyway because I thought it might not be clear on the solution.  YW

Comment: Can you separate function body and type definition?

Comment: That's essentially what the second example is doing. Other than that, not really.